# how can i use the magic methods correctly?

Tags: magento-1.9, magic-getter

I've thought about magic methods(based on php)in Magento help developers work more easily.Especially, getter method is pretty useful to create own custom module.

As far as i know, `get methods` has some rules for existing

1. use camelCase like getName() , getLastName()
2. format like $this->get`Variable`

Actually, i've search on Google, i couldn't find the what extactly i have to write on gray part. I mean that i don't know what i write as `variable`means extactly.

is it from field name base on table ? or any other stuffs?

And i want to know the part what i checked as `$order`->getShippingdescription() , `$product`->getName(). is it called frontname?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an object of a model class, your table column names are firstname, email_address, id. You can get this value following way:

```
$model->getFirstname(), 
$model->getEmailAddress()
```

etc. that means every underscore remove and next first letter should be capital letter.

N.B: If any method name you can find that are unavailable in table column, it must be an model class custom method. Example: **$order->getId()** returns **sales_flat_order** table **entity_id** column.

If method is not an column name then it must be present in model class. e.g: **$order->getPayment()** return payment model object and its present in **Mage_Sales_Model_Order** class.

Comment: awww i perfectly got it. Then, if i know a name of model class and the column name of table that the model class use, am i able to use getter(or setter method) without any problem ?

Comment: @3CE yes, you can.